# How can I reset a list after each loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to create a new list (self.Input/self.Output) each time the while loop is called. And append this new list to another list at the end of it (self.Input_full/self.Output_full).

I have tried to reset the list at the start of the while loop with either just setting them back to empty: self.Output = [[],[],[],[]]
or deleting the information held by them: del self.Output[:]
but this didn't work, since then I got empty lists in the Full lists

```
import threading

class PepperCommandEvaluator(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Input = [[],[],[],[]]
        self.Input_full = []
        self.Output = [[],[],[],[]]
        self.Output_full = []
        self.count = 0
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def send_thread(self):
        while self.count < 2:
            self.count = self.count + 1
            self.event.set()      
            sequence = [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,3,3]]
            for cmd in sequence:
                rospy.loginfo("sending command")
                rospy.Rate(0.5).sleep()
                msg = Twist()
                msg.linear.x = cmd[0]
                msg.linear.y = cmd[1]
                msg.angular.z = cmd[2]
                t = rospy.get_rostime()
                self.Input[0].append(cmd[0])
                self.Input[1].append(cmd[1])
                self.Input[2].append(cmd[2])
                self.Input[3].append(t.secs + t.nsecs * 1e-9)
            self.Input_full.append(self.Input)
            self.event.clear()

    def receive_thread(self,msg):
        if self.event.isSet():
            self.frame_id = msg.header.frame_id
            self.x_odom = msg.pose.pose.position.x
            self.y_odom = msg.pose.pose.position.y
            self.z_odom = msg.pose.pose.position.z
            self.ang_odom = msg.pose.pose.orientation.z
            self.time = msg.header.stamp.secs
            self.Output[0].append(self.x_odom)
            self.Output[1].append(self.y_odom)
            self.Output[2].append(self.ang_odom)
            self.Output[3].append(self.time)
        else:
            self.Output_full.append(self.Output)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tros = PepperCommandEvaluator()
    tros.send_thread()
```

My desired output is to get a new self.Input and self.Output_odom with each loop and append this list to the self.Input_full and self.Output_full_odom respectively.
In the end depending on the amount of times n the loop is ran, this should look like this:
self.Output_full = [[self.Output_1,self.Output_2,...,self.Output_n]]

Comment: Just put the list declaration at the top of the loop

Comment: Sounds like a reference issue, lists are usually handled by reference. When you save it, use `self.Input.copy()` then reset it at the start of the loop

Comment: What is `self.event` and when is it declared?

Comment: @MAO3J1m0Op it is a Threading module, forgot to paste it. I edited it in now

Comment: I cant reproduce it, its working for me (by just adding `self.Input = [[],[],[],[]]` before `for cmd in sequence:`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since lists in python are handled by reference, when you append the reference to `Input` to `Input_full`, then delete `Input`, you also delete the entry in `Input_full`. To avoid this, you want to append a copy of `Input`, then clear the real thing. You can also change the reference of `Input` to an empty list after appending it.

```
    def send_thread(self):
    while self.count < 2:
        self.count = self.count + 1
        self.event.set()      
        sequence = [[1,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,3,3]]
        self.Input = [[],[],[]] # Reassigning to a new list at the top
        for cmd in sequence:
            rospy.loginfo("sending command")
            rospy.Rate(0.5).sleep()
            msg = Twist()
            msg.linear.x = cmd[0]
            msg.linear.y = cmd[1]
            msg.angular.z = cmd[2]
            t = rospy.get_rostime()
            self.Input[0].append(cmd[0])
            self.Input[1].append(cmd[1])
            self.Input[2].append(cmd[2])
            self.Input[3].append(t.secs + t.nsecs * 1e-9)
        self.Input_full.append(self.Input)
        self.event.clear()
```